# Loss of regularity on the wave equation solution.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation, regularity-theory-of-pdes

On the Kirchoff's formula to the 3D wave equation solution $u(x,t)$, it's written in some books that if the initial conditions are $u(x,0):=f\in C^k$ and $u_t(x,0):=g\in C^{k-1}$, then the solution $u\in C^{k-1}$, why? I understand why $f$ must be once more differentiable than $g$, but since the solution is given by a integral over the sphere, doesn't that mean that one can differentiate the solution at least $k$ times?

> To simplify, let $h(y)$ be a $C^{k}$ function, then is it true that $u(x,t)=\int_{|y-x|=t} h(y) dS_y$ is a $C^{k}$ class function? Why not $C^{k+1}$?

What about the 2D case?

> Let $h(y)$ be a $C^{k}$ function, then is it true that $u(x,t)=\int_{|y-x|\leq t} h(y) dy$ is a $C^{k}$ class function?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your first question, I would write 
$$
u(t, \mathbf x)=t^2\int_{\mathbb S^2} h(t \mathbf y +\mathbf x)\, dS(\mathbf y).$$
So, formally at least 
$$
\partial_{\mathbf x}^\alpha u(t, \mathbf x) =t^2\int_{\mathbb S^2}\partial^\alpha_{\mathbf x} h(t \mathbf y +\mathbf x)\, dS(\mathbf y),$$
meaning that to differentiate $u$ $k$ times in $\mathbf x$ one needs $k$ derivatives of $h$. Same goes with time derivatives.

Comment: But why can't we differentiate one more time outside the integration sign, as we do in the 1D case (even though the integrand is not guaranteed to be differentiable anymore)? Writing $u(t,x)=\int_{x-t}^{x+t} h(y)  dy=t \int_{-1}^{1} h(x+yt) dy$ as you did.

Comment: That's different: there you are integrating on the full interval $[x-t, x+t]$ (assuming $t>0$, reverse order if $t<0$). In the 3d case you integrate on the surface of the sphere (which corresponds, in the 1d case, to evaluating a function at the boundary of an interval. This clearly does not improve regularity).

Comment: Anyway, I understand if you are not fully convinced, it is my fault, I am not being sufficiently clear. You raise a good point, but that concerns the 2d case, in which you integrate on a disk. Following your analogy, this should increase regularity, and maybe it does, I am not sure.

Comment: I got confused because there are some texts in which the author mentions this differentiability relation between the initial conditions and the solution is true for 2D as well, actually for every dimension higher than one...

Comment: @LeoMito: Thank you for accepting. I hope you are truly satisfied with my answer. You raise a good point with your last comment: in the even-dimension case, regularity should increase. I have no answer to this rightful objection of yours, frankly.

Comment: I got intuitively convinced by your first comment (because in the 3D case since we don't integrate in the radius direction $t$ which "is inside the sphere", then we don't gain another differentiation in $t$), this is enough for now, specially because the real problem might be my poor calculus knowledge. Thanks anyway.